# Python recursion tree (for loop)

Tags: python

I am working on tree based program on python. I need to rewrite this function using recursion and liquidate all of these for-loops:

Example of my function:

```
def items_on_level(full_tree, level):
    for key0, value0 in full_tree.items():
        for key1, value1 in value0.items():
            for key2, value2 in value1.items():
                for key3, value3 in value2.items():
                    print(key3)
```

Input:  
- level - level of my recursion tree 
- full_tree - dict with parents and children

```
{<Category: test>: {<Category: dkddk>: {}, <Category: test2>: {<Category: test3>: {}, <Category: test5>: {<Category: kfpokpok>: {}}}}
```

Function should return: all the objects on current level
Help! Thanks!

Comment: What do the `<>` in `<Category: test>` do?

Comment: I think I know which class this is for. I wonder if I should send the prof an email

Answer (score 2):

```
def itemsOnLevel(root, level):
  if not level:
    return list(root.keys())
  else:
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([itemsOnLevel(v, level-1) for k,v in root.items()]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
itemsOnLevel = lambda r, l: (
    lambda f, r, l: f (f, r, l) ) (
    lambda f, r, l: [_ for _ in r.keys () ] if not l else
    [i for k in r.values () for i in f (f, k, l - 1) ], r, l)
```

Comment: I don't think there's ever a good reason to write recursive lambda expressions in Python. Use regular functions, it will break your brain less.

Comment: @Blckknght Well, my answer would not have looked like this, if it wasn't obvious that it was a homework assignment. But nevertheless it works...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help a bit

```
if(full_tree != {}):

    for node in return_list_current_level(full_tree):
        items_on_level(node, level+1)
else:
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def onl(r,l):
  if l:
    obj=[]
    for i in [onl(v,l-1) for v in r.values()]:
      obj.extend(i)
    return obj
  return r.keys()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to rewrite this function as a template tag?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be.

Comment: And one more question. How to write a template tag that returns all child objects (from the dictionary full_tree). 

The problem is that the template should be used variable.
Something like this:
{{ child item_name }}
item_name - name of the object

This is the most important for me now. I will appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: I'm trying to create a tree, but unfortunately I can not use the mptt and other libraries. Thanks.